# expandable listview scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

in my application I have 3 expandableListview as shown here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/filter_items_background"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- Gender -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listSelectionHeaderTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/filter_groups_background"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/filterFragment__itemHeight"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/filter_interestedin"
            android:textColor="#8F8F8F"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/filter_items_background"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/filterFragment__itemHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/men_itemText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/filter_men"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/men_toggleButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_switch_drawable"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn="" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/filter_items_background"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/filterFragment__itemHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/women_itemText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="@string/filter_women"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/women_toggleButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_switch_drawable"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn="" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- Age -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/filter_groups_background"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/filterFragment__itemHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ageHeaderTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/filter_age"
                android:textColor="#8F8F8F"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ageValuesTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Sample"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/filter_items_background"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" >

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/age_seekBar_from"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/age_seekBar_to"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
            android:saveEnabled="true" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
            android:saveEnabled="true" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
            android:saveEnabled="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is when I open one of expandablelistview the others expandablelistview not showing... I want open one child of expandablelistview and enable scroll and others expandablelistview.